# SQL Unpivoting data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I am trying to pivot column values (Month_End) which I have done per a few KB's but then I also need to unpivot other columns (PAC_Contract, PAC_Projected_Cost, JTD_Actual) into row values but am getting confused and not sure if PIVOT is the right want to attack this.

SQL2012

This is the Table

[image: Database Records]

This is what I would like to get to

[image: Desired State]

This is where I am currently at but it seems like the scenic route :)

```
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-- Get the last 3 Month End Dates
SELECT TOP 3
    @columns += QUOTENAME(Month_End) + ','

FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master
GROUP BY Month_End
ORDER BY Month_End desc;

-- Remove the last comma
SET @columns = LEFT(@columns, LEN(@columns) - 1);

PRINT @columns;

-- Construct the PIVOT
SET @sql ='
    SELECT * FROM(
        SELECT
        Job_Number,
        Month_End,
        ''PAC Contract'' AS Column_Name,
        PAC_Contract AS Value
    FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master WHERE Job_Number = ''A1327''
    UNION
    SELECT
      Job_Number,
      Month_End,
    ''PAC Projected Cost'' AS Column_Name,
    PAC_Projected_Cost AS Value
    FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master WHERE Job_Number = ''A1327''
    UNION
    SELECT
      Job_Number,
      Month_End,
      ''JTD_Actual_Cost'' AS Column_Name,
      JTD_Actual_Cost AS Value
    FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master WHERE Job_Number = ''A1327''
    ) d
    PIVOT(
        SUM(Value)
        FOR Month_End IN ('+ @columns +')
    ) AS ppc ;';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any way to avoid dynamic SQL.

If the Pivot works, I see no particular reason not to use it.  If you prefer a bit more control, you can use dynamic SQL to generate select items with conditional aggregation similar to what GMB has shown, but I believe you should use `SUM()` instead of `MAX()`.

As GMB also suggested, `CROSS APPLY (VALUES ...)` is a simpler way to unpivot your original data vs multiple `UNION`ed selects. SQL does have an UNPIVOT clause, but it might not have the flexibility that `CROSS APPLY (VALUES ...)` gives you.

Lastly, you can also pass parameters (such as job number) into your dynamic SQL by declaring the parameter(s) and passing the value(s) in the `EXECUTE sp_executesql` statement.

```
-- Dynamic SQL with conditional aggregation
DECLARE @columns NVARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @sql     NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT TOP 3
    @columns += '
        , SUM(CASE WHEN M.Month_End = '''
        + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Month_End, 20)
        + ''' THEN A.Value END) AS '
        + QUOTENAME(Month_End)
FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master
GROUP BY Month_End
ORDER BY Month_End desc;

SET @sql ='
    SELECT M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name' + @columns + '
    FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master M
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            (''PAC Contract'', M.PAC_Contract),
            (''PAC Projected Cost'', M.PAC_Projected_Cost),
            (''JTD_Actual_Cost'', M.JTD_Actual_Cost)
    ) A(Column_Name, Value)
    WHERE M.Job_Number = @JobNo
    GROUP BY M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name
    ORDER BY M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name';

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, N'@JobNo VARCHAR(100)', @JobNo = 'A1327'
```

This will generate dynamic SQL like:

```
    SELECT M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name
        , SUM(CASE WHEN M.Month_End = '2022-08-01' THEN A.Value END) AS [2022-08-01]
        , SUM(CASE WHEN M.Month_End = '2022-07-01' THEN A.Value END) AS [2022-07-01]
        , SUM(CASE WHEN M.Month_End = '2022-06-01' THEN A.Value END) AS [2022-06-01]
    FROM _rec_spectrum_CTC_Master M
    CROSS APPLY (
        VALUES
            ('PAC Contract', M.PAC_Contract),
            ('PAC Projected Cost', M.PAC_Projected_Cost),
            ('JTD_Actual_Cost', M.JTD_Actual_Cost)
    ) A(Column_Name, Value)
    WHERE M.Job_Number = @JobNo
    GROUP BY M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name
    ORDER BY M.Job_Number, A.Column_Name
```

See [This db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cMPk-AmQ) for a working demo.

Answer (score 1):

You would typically unpivot the columns to rows, then pivot the dates against new column:

```
select x.col
    max(case when month_end = '2022-06-01' then val end) as val_06_01,
    max(case when month_end = '2022-07-01' then val end) as val_07_01,
    max(case when month_end = '2022-08-01' then val end) as val_08_01
from mytable t
cross apply ( values 
    ('PAC_Contract', t.pac_contract), 
    ('PAC_PROJECTED_COST', t.pac_projected_cost), 
    ('JTD_Actual_Cost', t.jtd_actual_cost) 
) x(col, val)
group by x.col
```

Note that this only works on a fixed list of initial columns and dates ; if you want something more flexible than that, then you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: I would like it to be dynamic.  When I run the report each month I would like to pull back the last 3 months.